# The fourth parameter in pthread_create function

Tags: c++, pthreads

Code like this:

```
int code = pthread_create(&d->thread_id, &attr, QThreadPrivate::start, this);
```

which `QThreadPrivate::start` is a static function.

So,what use is the fourth parameter `this`? And what is the difference if `this` is replaced by `NULL`?

Answer (score 3):

The fourth parameter of `pthread_create` is passed untouched to the thread function and allows that function to change behaviour based on that argument.

OpenGroup documentation for `pthread_create`, detailing this, can be found [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html).

In this case, it's simply passing the pointer to the current object, presumably so that the `start` function can use that to access member variables for the specific object.

If you pass `NULL` instead, the created thread will get `NULL` and won't be able to access object specific data (without crashing and burning badly with a null pointer dereference).

You may think that, because `QThreadPrivate::start` is a static function, it wouldn't be able to access non-static members any way (since it generally doesn't have an object to work on).

But that only applies to implicit access - there's nothing stopping you from accessing object data through an *explicit* `this` pointer, providing you follow the access rules (e.g., no access to private data).

Answer (score 3):

This is a common idiom. You want to start a thread, but you want that thread to operate on a specific object. So you need to pass the thread a pointer to the object you want it to operate on. If you're within a member function for that object, the `this` pointer points to the object you're operating on. You can't pass a pointer to a member function directly (because the type would be different), so you use a static member function whose sole purpose is to cast the `this` pointer back to the correct type and run a non-static member function.

If you changed `this` to `NULL`, the thread would have no idea what object it was supposed to operate on. Likely, `QThreadPrivate::start` would fault or fail, since it would be unable to invoke a non-static member function on the instance without a pointer to that instance.

Say you have a class that has a normal member function that takes no parameters and returns no parameters. You have some code that has no idea about your class or any of its structures. You want to give that code enough information to call that member function on a particular class instance. What do you pass it? You can't pass it a pointer to the member function because with no idea about your class, it can't call a normal class member function. Answer: You pass it a pointer to a static member function whose implementation calls the normal member function, and you pass it a pointer to the instance whose method you want it to invoke.

Answer (score 1):

The fourth parameter is passed to the thread when it starts. QThreadPrivate::start can use it (after an appropriate cast) to call an object specific member function.