# C++: Creating new thread using pthread_create, to run a class member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have the following class:

```
class A
{
    private:
        int starter()
        {
             //TO_DO: pthread_create()
        }

        void* threadStartRoutine( void *pThis );
}
```

I want to create a thread from inside starter() to run threadStartRoutine(). I get compile time errors with regard to the third argument, which should take the address of the start routine.

What would be the correct way to call pthread_create() to create a new thread that starts executing threadStartRoutine() ?

I have come across articles online that say that most compilers do not allow non-static member functions to be invoked using pthread_create(). Is this true? What is the reason behind this?

I am compiling my program on Linux-x64 using G++.

Comment: make thread start routine static

Comment: @neagoegab: I cannot make threadStartRoutine static. The class is multi-threaded. Making threadStartRoutine static results in memory leak errors that I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The fouth parameter in pthread_create function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920441/the-fouth-parameter-in-pthread-create-function)

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot convert '*void(MyClass::*)(void*) to void*(*)(void*) in pthread_create function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006097/cannot-convert-voidmyclassvoid-to-voidvoid-in-pthread-create-fu)

Comment: Unless you're stuck in the past for some reason, you should consider the standard thread library. And even if you are stuck in the past, Boost.Thread might be a better option than rolling your own wrapper around pthreads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the `threadStartRountine()` as `static`:

```
static void* threadStartRoutine( void *pThis );
```

Otherwise, the type of `threadStartRoutine()` is:

```
void* (A::*)(void*)
```

which is not the type of function pointer that `pthread_create()` requires.

Comment: I cannot. The class is multi-threaded. Making threadStartRoutine static results in memory leak errors that I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: @ShaileshTainwala, I am unsure how either of those two arguments prevent you from making the function `static`?

Comment: The sentence "The class is multi-threaded" makes absolutely no sense. That's not how C++ and programming work.

Comment: By "the class is multi-threaded" I assume you mean that multiple threads might use the same object.  As hmjd says, I don't see what that has to do with the problem.  Naturally using an object in multiple threads will make it harder to correctly destroy it; but that probably has nothing to do with the start routine.

Comment: Sorry, bad language. The program that consumes this Class A was modified and made multi-threaded. This change has led to several memory errors that are very difficult to pin-point due to environment constraints. I have traced them to this part of the program, using *exhaustive* trial-and-error. All my research says that mixing static member functions and multi-threading is a bad idea. Hence the question.

Comment: @ShaileshTainwala Your memory leak is most likely not caused by making a method static. Use valgrind to pinpoint where you are leaking memory.

Comment: @ShaileshTainwala: Do not make the function static. Instead write a new static function that calls yours, and use this new function as argument to `pthread_create()`. And everybody happy! Naturally you will need to pass on the `this` argument so that the static function can call a non-static one. But that's why you have the `pThis` argument.

Comment: @anio - Using Valgrind, gdb or other tools is not possible, I am building a library for a much larger program. One which I cannot rebuild with debugging info.

Comment: @ShaileshTainwala - they're functions, ie. code, with stack parameters, ie. different for each thread.  There is no problem calling a static function from multiple threads, passing a 'this' pointer and then calling a method on 'this'.  Problems arise when involving static data mambers that are shared by all callers.

Comment: @ShaileshTainwala That makes no sense, why can't you build with debugging info? It is a simple compiler argument: -g. I've run massive programs under valgrind and found memory leaks.

Comment: I think rodrigo has the right idea about my guess is that you are using a static function in some particular way that happens to be a subtle anti-pattern.  As for not using these debugging info - even if you could recompile the bigger program, you should also have a test rig so that you can isolate your library.

Comment: @rodrigo: Technically, you must only pass functions to `pthread_create` which have `extern "C"` linkage.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Could you give a reference for this? I don't see why the linkage of the function should matter at all. And the `extern "C"` syntax only changes the name mangling, right? (and maybe something about exceptions...).

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a reason for using pthreads? c++11 is here, why not just use that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void doWork()
{
   while(true) 
   {
      // Do some work;
      sleep(1); // Rest
      std::cout << "hi from worker." << std::endl;
   }
}

int main(int, char**)
{

  std::thread worker(&doWork);
  std::cout << "hello from main thread, the worker thread is busy." << std::endl;
  worker.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a normal function as a wrapper.  As hjmd says, a static function is probably the nicest kind of normal function.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using the native pthreads interface, then you *must* provide an ordinary function as the entry point. A typical example:

```
class A
{
private:
    int starter()
    {
        pthread_t thr;
        int res = pthread_create(&thr, NULL, a_starter, this);
        // ...
    }
public:
    void run();
};

extern "C" void * a_starter(void * p)
{
    A * a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(p);
    a->run();
    return NULL;
}
```