# Creating A Thread and Calling Function Of A Class

Tags: c++, multithreading, struct, pthreads

How can I access the function of a class while creating a thread?

When I remove the class it works well, so long as I don't have to use an object to access that function.

Also, I'm receiving this error: `error: argument of type ‘void* (MyClass::)(void*)’ does not match ‘void* (*)(void*)’`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;

struct thread_data
{
    int tid;
    char *msg;
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    void *MyFunction(void *myarg)
    {

        struct thread_data *td = (struct thread_data *)myarg;
        cout << "Inside MyFunction With Thread Id : " << td->tid << endl;
        cout << "Message Of Thread Id " << td->tid << " is : "<< td->msg << endl;
        //sleep(1);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass o1,o2,o3;
    pthread_t obj1,obj2,obj3;
    struct thread_data td1,td2,td3;

    td1.tid=1;
    td1.msg="First Thread";

    pthread_create(&obj1,NULL,o1.MyFunction,(void *)&td1);

    td2.tid=2;
    td2.msg="Second Thread";

    pthread_create(&obj2,NULL,o2.MyFunction,(void *)&td2);

    td3.tid=3;
    td3.msg="Third Thread";

    pthread_create(&obj3,NULL,o3.MyFunction,(void *)&td3);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can make a non-member function (or static member function) that calls the member function.

Comment: Look here for answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160175/c-creating-new-thread-using-pthread-create-to-run-a-class-member-function

Comment: std::bind may helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with boost, something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    void myFunction(void* arg) {};
};

boost::function<void(void)> f = boost::bind(&MyClass::myFunction,&MyClassInstance,&MyStructInstance); 
boost::function<void(void)>* fCopy = new boost::function<void(void)> (function); //create a copy on the heap

void wrappedFunction(void* arg)
{

   boost::function<void(void)> *func = (boost::f<void(void)>* ) (arg);
   (*func)();
   delete(func);
}

pthread_t id;
pthread_create(&id,NULL,&wrappedFunction,functionCopy);
```